# Django 1.6.8 with ADMIN_URL

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I would like to add the https://github.com/RobCombs/django-locking project to my Django 1.6.8 project's admin interface. I understand that this locking code is meant for an older version of Django, but I'd like to see if it's possible to install anyway.

While following step 7, I'm encountering this exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_locking-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/locking/admin.py", line 15, in <module>
    class LockableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_locking-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/locking/admin.py", line 17, in LockableAdmin
    class Media:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_locking-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/locking/admin.py", line 21, in Media
    _s.ADMIN_URL + "ajax/variables.js",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ADMIN_URL'
```

Indeed my settings.py has nothing about ADMIN_URL. I can't find any documentation on how to set this, or otherwise proceed with adding this locking functionality.

Is it possible to continue from here on Django 1.6.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the construction with getattr() in [settings.py](https://github.com/RobCombs/django-locking/blob/master/locking/settings.py) of django-locking doesn't work anymore (because Django's Settings object raises AttributeError?) which is surprising to me. I can't test right now, unfortunately.

The good news is that simply setting `ADMIN_URL = '/admin/'` in your settings will most likely fix this issue.

The bad news is that you'll probably run into a few more that may not be easy to fix, but who knows...

Comment: That addressed it. It's mostly working now - just have some directory not found issues to sort out. Thanks for your help!